# Rotate entire scene to portrait

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm using a 90 degrees rotated monitor to display my three.js application. The device I'm using does not know its own rotation.

Can I rotate everything so I have y where I have x now, and so forth?

I tried in CSS with transform:rotate(90deg), but that results in heavy letterboxing.

Comment: Is `camera.up.set( - 1, 0, 0 )` what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes! That works (with 0,0,-1) - but now OrbitControls auto rotation gives weird results, almost like it rotates in a 8-shape pattern. Tried updating to the latest three dev build and got the latest OrbitControls, but same result.

Comment: Here's the example http://mortenjust.com/floorflow/3D/archi-so.html

Comment: Update `OrbitControls.js`.

Comment: ah - got the 9 days old version from the dev repo - now it works with mouse orbiting. The auto rotation is on the wrong axis, though :) I tried hacking it by changing rotateLeft to rotateUp in OrbitControls.js, but that produces a weird result. Here's an example with rotateLeft: http://mortenjust.com/floorflow/3D/archi-so2.html?393

Comment: Add `scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 ) );` and you will see the direction of the negative-z axis. (The positive-z axis is blue.) `OrbitControls` is working as designed.